# php get only values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

This is a very basic quesion i know but im facing difficulties. I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10772
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10775
    )

)
```

or you can say:

```
array(12) {
[0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(10772) } [1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(10775) }
```

but i need only the value in a string format like:

```
"10772,10775" or array("10772", "10775")
```

how can i achieve that.

Comment: You need to loop through your array to get what you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php) function:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'id' => 123456
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 52458
    ),
);

$id_array = array_column($array, 'id');

print_r($id_array);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123456
    [1] => 52458
)
```

for PHP version < `5.5` you can use:

```
$data = array_map(function($element) {
    return $element['id'];
}, $array);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: this is only available in php 5.5+

Comment: @andrew but it's a good answer. OP doesn't said the version he needs, so the answer is the best and simplest way

Comment: edited for php version < `5.5`

Comment: thank you very much for fast answer yes im not worried about php version as im using 5.6

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `array_map` function

```
$ids = array_map(function($row){ return $row['id']; }, $array);
```

Check this link for more info
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php