# How to select only the first link from PHP string?

Tags: php, arrays

I tried the following code to get only the first url from the string. But it not working.
The `print_r($matches[0]);` is showing array result. but the `echo $matches[0];` is displaying nothing, what went wrong here ?
I just want the "https://www.amazon.in/b?node=21021782031&pf_rd_r=Z8266H8XJMQGEZMB0X44&pf_rd_p=00f7186e-02c5-40c7-9f15-9f2d65d70297" to be displayed and remove all other text and links.

```
<?php
$string = "Samsung Galaxy S20 (Black) https://www.amazon.in/b?node=21021782031&pf_rd_r=Z8266H8XJMQGEZMB0X44&pf_rd_p=00f7186e-02c5-40c7-9f15-9f2d65d70297 afdsfdsf d https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433139/php-get-only-values-from-an-array and  https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox";
$regex = '#https?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[0]);

echo "</br>";

echo $matches[0];
?>
```

the result should output only the first link from `$string` like following

```
https://www.amazon.in/b?node=21021782031&pf_rd_r=Z8266H8XJMQGEZMB0X44&pf_rd_p=00f7186e-02c5-40c7-9f15-9f2d65d70297
```

Comment: Why do you want the echo to show the result? Also change your '</br>' to '</pre>'

Comment: by echo I am just testing the code, the intention is to add it with another larger code.

Comment: Does the print_r show what you want?

Comment: but it shows all the URLs , I just want to get only first URL.

Comment: Can you write an example of would be the correct and valid output?

Comment: @RafaelMora, it was mentioned in the question. the result should output only the first link from `$string`. Edited question.

Comment: I need you to write the first link, what is the first link?

Comment: @RafaelMora  https://www.amazon.in/b?node=21021782031&pf_rd_r=Z8266H8XJMQGEZMB0X44&pf_rd_p=00f7186e-02c5-40c7-9f15-9f2d65d70297

Comment: Please confirm that the first link can be separeted by the char '&'

Comment: @RafaelMora , no the link should be full, it will contain '&' , '=', it is important.

Comment: @RafaelMora the link begins with "https..." and  ends with"....-9f2d65d70297"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make it this way using explode

```
$string = "Samsung Galaxy S20 (Black) https://www.amazon.in/b?node=21021782031&pf_rd_r=Z8266H8XJMQGEZMB0X44&pf_rd_p=00f7186e-02c5-40c7-9f15-9f2d65d70297 afdsfdsf d https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433139/php-get-only-values-from-an-array and  https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox";

foreach(explode(" ",$string) as $first_occurrence) {
  if (strpos($first_occurrence, 'http') !== false) { break;}
}

echo $first_occurrence;
//https://www.amazon.in/b?node=21021782031&pf_rd_r=Z8266H8XJMQGEZMB0X44&pf_rd_p=00f7186e-02c5-40c7-9f15-9f2d65d70297
```