# remove text and only return the first link in PHP

Tags: php

Here is the code I found in stackoverflow, but it has an issue, someone help me to get it fixed.

```
<?php
$string = "Apple iPhone SE (Black, 64 GB)
http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/apple-iphone-se-black-64-gb/p/itm832dd5963a08d?pid=MOBFRFXHCKWDAC4A&cmpid=product.share.pp";

foreach(explode(" ",$string) as $first_occurrence) {
  if (strpos($first_occurrence, 'http') !== false) { break;}
}

echo $first_occurrence;
?>
```

The result is

```
GB) http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/apple-iphone-se-black-64-gb/p/itm832dd5963a08d?pid=MOBFRFXHCKWDAC4A&cmpid=product.share.pp
```

There is an unwanted `GB)` 
There is a line break after "...64 GB)", if I remove that, the code seems to be working correctly. But I also want to make it work with line breaks.

How can I get accurate output as following?

```
http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/apple-iphone-se-black-64-gb/p/itm832dd5963a08d?pid=MOBFRFXHCKWDAC4A&cmpid=product.share.pp
```

Here is another more complicated string,

```
$string = "Samsung Galaxy S20 (Black) https://www.amazon.in/b?node=21021782031&pf_rd_r=Z8266H8XJMQGEZMB0X44&pf_rd_p=00f7186e-02c5-40c7-9f15-9f2d65d70297 afdsfdsf d https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433139/php-get-only-values-from-an-array and  https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox";
```

The result should be

```
https://www.amazon.in/b?node=21021782031&pf_rd_r=Z8266H8XJMQGEZMB0X44&pf_rd_p=00f7186e-02c5-40c7-9f15-9f2d65d70297
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more easily achieved using regex. [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will return the first match inside the string:

```
$string = "Apple iPhone SE (Black, 64 GB)
http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/apple-iphone-se-black-64-gb/p/itm832dd5963a08d?pid=MOBFRFXHCKWDAC4A&cmpid=product.share.pp";

preg_match('~https?://[^\s]*~', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Output:

```
http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/apple-iphone-se-black-64-gb/p/itm832dd5963a08d?pid=MOBFRFXHCKWDAC4A&cmpid=product.share.pp
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ZaRuV)

Comment: thanks for the reply. But there is one problem. If there is multiple links, it only detects the last link. How can I detect the first link, always. New example string added in question. Please check.

Comment: @MalavikaP it works fine for that string: https://3v4l.org/WBSdQ

Comment: thank You Nick, it works, didn't worked for me earlier, maybe it was the cache :-)

Comment: I like your solution. it is more universal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too:

```
$string = "Apple iPhone SE (Black, 64 GB)
http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/apple-iphone-se-black-64-gb/p/itm832dd5963a08d?pid=MOBFRFXHCKWDAC4A&cmpid=product.share.pp";

foreach(explode("http",$string) as $first_occurrence) {
  if (strpos($first_occurrence, '://') !== false) { break;}
}

echo $first_occurrence;
```

Hope it helps.